# How to get the tool id for eclipse headless build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse has a [headless build option](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/) and in the documentation they say we can add or replace tool options

> Replace a tool option value:           -T          {toolid} {optionid=value}
>
> Append to a tool option value:         -Ta         {toolid} {optionid=value}
>
> Prepend to a tool option value:        -Tp         {toolid} {optionid=value}
>
> Remove a tool option:                  -Tr         {toolid} {optionid=value}

How would someone find the {toolid} value for a build option?

I would like to change the command line arguments for this command

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "KTV_Rear.elf"  "KTV_Rear.hex"
```

to

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "KTV_Rear.elf"  "KTV_Rear.bin"
```

I have not been able to find any documentation on how to get the tool id to pass to the -T command. Any help would be appreciated.

==================== UPDATE ========================
[image]
I tried to figure out what the tool ids were in the way that HighCommander4 suggested. Searching for "tool id" in the project gives

```
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.compiler.1172133377" name="GNU ARM Cross C++ Compiler" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.compiler"/>
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.linker.707543027" name="GNU ARM Cross C++ Linker" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.linker">
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.archiver.1908892168" name="GNU ARM Cross Archiver" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.archiver"/>
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.createlisting.1903643389" name="GNU ARM Cross Create Listing" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.createlisting">
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.compiler.270131667" name="GNU ARM Cross C++ Compiler" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.compiler"/>
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.linker.1091026714" name="GNU ARM Cross C++ Linker" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.cpp.linker">
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.archiver.1404415533" name="GNU ARM Cross Archiver" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.archiver"/>
<tool id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.createlisting.292770688" name="GNU ARM Cross Create Listing" superClass="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.tool.createlisting">
```

The output of the build window for the command I need to modify is

```
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross Create Flash Image
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "KTV_Rear.elf"  "KTV_Rear.hex"
```

It does not seem obvious which one of the tool ids might relate to arm-none-eabi-objcopy. I tried using the string for the tool id for the archiver with no luck.

I found [this link](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cdt-dev/msg16004.html) that seems related

Comment: I'm not 100% confident in this, but if you open up the `.cproject` file of a CDT managed build project, there are entries in there of the form `<tool id ="...">`. I would expect those are the IDs in question.

Answer (score 0):

At the .cproject file you can find the tool id (use the superClass field, without the number) and for each tool you can find a list of options ids. At the invocation line you need to specify the tool id, the option id and the value for the option, like in the following example (adding my_lib_location to the libraries search path):

```
-Tp cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.c.linker.exe.release gnu.c.link.option.paths=my_lib_location
```